# Reference not returning nil even if deallocated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, release-management

I have run into a real hard one here.

My class is self-created (a `+ (void) start;`-method) which is sent a delegate.
I need to send the delegate a few messages through delegate-selectors. To check if the delegate was released, I have tried `if (delegate == nil/NULL)`, but even if it really is released, it still says it wasn't.

How do I go around to fix this? (delegate is assigned to an `id`)

This is how my app is built up:

```
AppDelegate
> NavController
>> TableView 
>>> Post 
>>>> GetData
```

GetData is the self-created class. Post is the delegate of GetData, and is released by TableView/NavController. After releasing Post, it is also set to nil.
In other words, **GetData does not release it's delegate**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't check if an object was released. Another object could've come along and occupied the same memory space, becoming indistinguishable with the original object.

The user of a class with a delegate is responsible for setting the delegate to `nil` when the delegate object is released. It's not detectable by the object itself.

Comment: What if the class does not even release the delegate, some other superior class does that (and does also set it to nil…)?

Comment: That's fine, just so long as the class's delegate reference gets set to nil before the delegate itself is released.

Comment: In your case, where `Post` seems to own `GetData`, just add a `delegate = nil` in the `-dealloc` method.

Comment: I don't think you understand, GetData is not _owned_ by Post, GetData is "started" by Post (`[GetData startDownloadWithDelegate:self];`, a `+ (void)`-method.)

Comment: Then what owns the `GetData` object? Does the `GetData` method own itself? In that situation, it might be a good idea to retain the delegate of `GetData`—if there's no part of the object graph that allows `Post` to notify `GetData` when it is deallocated, then a direct retain may be your best option.

Comment: But if that's not the behavior you want (i.e. you want a `Post` object disappearing to remove the associated `GetData` object), then you may need to change the ownership semantics of those classes.

Answer (score 5):

Deallocating the content of a pointer *does not* set the pointer to NULL automatically. You need to do it explicitly, e.g.

```
[delegate release];
delegate = nil;
```

Comment: That is probably where my problem lays. See updated question (in a few minutes)

Comment: @Emil: Without any code (those relating to assigning the `delegate`) it is hard to know what is your actual problem.

Comment: I fixed it by retaining the delegate, as the GetData-class owns itself.